# Pulling values from list's

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list.

```
[NormalizedReference(book=<Book.MATTHEW: 40>, start_chapter=18, start_verse=12, end_chapter=18, end_verse=14, end_book=None), NormalizedReference(book=<Book.LUKE: 42>, start_chapter=15, start_verse=3, end_chapter=15, end_verse=7, end_book=None)]
```

How can I get the book value or end book value??

Python3

Comment: How is `NormalizedReference` is defined? How do you access it's attributes?

Comment: Do you want to access the "book value" for every instance in the list or a specific one?

Comment: I just want to get the book=<ThisPart>

Comment: its a list like mylist = []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details here -> https://pypi.org/project/pythonbible/

**STEP 1** : Converting a normalized scripture reference into a list of integer verse ids

**STEP 2** : Get the verse text

```
import pythonbible as bible

verse_text = bible.get_verse_text(1001001, version=bible.Version.KING_JAMES)
```

**Output :**

```
'In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.'
```

**To get verse id -**

Consider reference for `Genesis 1:1-4:`

```
import pythonbible as bible

reference = bible.NormalizedReference(bible.Book.GENESIS, 1, 1, 1, 4)
verse_ids = bible.convert_reference_to_verse_ids(reference)
```

The conversion functionality would return the following list of verse id integers:

`[1001001, 1001002, 1001003, 1001004]`

Comment: Yea but how do i get a Verse id from something like `Matthew 18:12-14 and Luke 15:3-7`

Comment: I want to be able to pull up the versers that i say so like Mathew 1:12-14

Comment: @BugleTV yeah so do something like `bible.Book.GENESIS, 1, 1, 1,2 14`

Comment: Ok but i want to be able to do Mathew 1:1-5 and it get Chapter 1 verse 1,5

Comment: @BugleTV I would recommend you to go through the documentation once, if still you have any doubts , you can ask me again :)